# access localize css file through SharePoint designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

1) how can i access _layout/1033/styles/custom.css file with SharePoint Designer ?

2) if i created a folder named 1033 through SharePoint Design in Style Library. What setting i have to make in master page to pick localized folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_layout is a virtual directory mapped to the 14 hive. Altering of these files directly is not recommend and I believe is not supported as these files can be overwritten at runtime.

If you must use sharepoint designer then your best bet is to make a copy of this file and place it in the style library.Then update your site to use the new CSS file loaded in your style library.

Comment: how can i register localized css file to master page and file is created in style library